# Using views with 1:N relation QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

Working with PostgreSQL basic view in QGIS I noticed that:

```
Select *
from t1
where t1.column = 'some_condition'
```

Views doesn't support constraints according to this topic: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667508/how-to-add-primary-key-to-view

My question is: *Is some way to use  1:N relation QGIS with PostreSQL views?*
When I try to create this relation in *QGIS - Project - properties* using View + table_relation: not load correctlly.

Otherwise, when I used spatial_table (with PK constraint) + table relation: works correctlly.

Someone have any idea?

Comment: Postgres DOES support constraints. It won't support adding primary keys to a view, which is a different thing

Comment: That's true. Revised and corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you cannot create a **primary key** on a view, you can create a column having **unique distinct values** which you can use as a primary key in QGIS.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.myview AS 
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.id, t1.name, t1.blablabla) AS V_UID, 
         t1.*
  FROM t1
  WHERE t1.column = 'some_condition';
```

What is extremely important is that the `order by` clause field combination leads to unique combination (that is, no two rows have the same values in those fields)

That being said, this example is a bad one as you could simply put a primary key on `t1`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @JGH. It worked exactly as I wanted.
Greetings